# Mantain coordinate of a point in a fullscreen image

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, css-animations

I've a fullscreen container (100wv 100wh)

**Objective:**

I want to show a specific portion of an image as a background (chessboard) to that container.
There is another image(pawn) that I want to position in a specific coordinate of the background-image.

**Problem:**

When the screen resize, the background image show the rest of the image that was cropped and that's fine. It even scale to match the height of the container (100% width).
The problem is that I'm not able to mantain the same coordinate of the "pawn" image on the "chessboard" image when the screen resize and the image correctly scale.

**Example of a (not) solution ( doesn'work, it's just solution a tried)**

```html
<div className="fullscreen">
  <div className="chessboard">
    <div className="pawn">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<style>
  .fullscreen {
    position: relative;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
  }

  .chessboard {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url('/images/chessboard.png');
    background-size: "auto 100%";
    background-position: "20% 80%";
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }

  .pawn {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20%;
    left: 20%;
    width: 20px;
    height: 50px;
    background: url('/images/pawn.png');
    background-size: "contain";
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }
</style>
```

I Except that from something like this (red line is what the viewport is actually showing in fullscreen):
[image]

on resize it become this (note that the the resizing viewport just show more of the image on the right and on the top) :

[image]

Instead the background image move it's position, and I'm losing the pawn original one.

I'm fine with the image scaling, it should. And I'm fine with it showing the rest of the cropped image when width resize.
The only problem it's that I couldn't find a combination of background-size, background-position,
of the chessboard and bottom/left of the pawn to mantain the same block on the chessboard.

(I need the pawn to be clickable, solutions that use two background-image aren't valid)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi @Vincenzo, welcome to SO! Could you post an MVE of the code you've tried so far?

Comment: You need to have a container the size of the board and position the pieces in % terms within it so they maintain their positioning on resizing. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example - creating a snippet which demonstrates the problem will help us give an answer.